# New Templates Not Deploying with TDS

Tags: tds, update-packages

I'm having a weird problem where not all of my template items are deploying via `TDS's` update file, but only for a single environment.

When I upload the `update` file to `/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx`, and analyze it on my local machine, I can see the items that are not being deployed.

When I upload the same `update` file to the problem environment it doesn't list the files I want to deploy at all. In fact, it lists about 100 fewer files in the analysis.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Comment: Is there anything in common amongst the items that don't get deployed? (All under one path, all have a special character, etc.)

Comment: Is there a difference in your TDS project properties for different build configurations?  e.g. Debug vs Release might have different settings that are excluding items.

Comment: They are all under one path, under the templates. It's a new section a developer is building. Other new items are showing up and deploying to the problem environment.

Comment: The Deployment Property Manager for the section is not different than its sibling sections, which deploy no problem.

Comment: Is everyone using the same version of the TDS plugin?

Comment: Is your TDS package named the same as other packages? Any chance you are looking at an old package on the problem environment?

Comment: Everyone is using the same version of TDS. I'm not looking at an old package. Wish it was something that simple. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. There was an issue with our continuous delivery system not being set up correctly for the new environment, so it wasn't deploying the update file at all. Apparently, if an item does not exist in the target system, the item will not show in the analysis when ran through /sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx. That was apparently the source of my confusion.